# TypeError: generatecode() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, class, tkinter, arguments, self

I have the code below:

```py
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame): 
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    
    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("COD:WWII Codes")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        codeButton = Button(
                        self, 
                        text="Generate Code", 
                        command=self.generatecode
                     )
        codeButton.place(x=0, y=0)

    def generatecode():
        f = open("C:/Programs/codes.txt", "r")
        t.insert(1.0. f.red())

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Then, I got the error below:

> TypeError: generatecode() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

So, how can I solve the error?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. You have 2 definitions of `generatecode()`. `self.generatecode()` is a bound method, meaning `self` will be passed as the first argument.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

When you call a method on a class (such as `generatecode()` in this case), Python automatically passes `self` as the first argument to the function. So when you call `self.my_func()`, it's more like calling `MyClass.my_func(self)`.

So when Python tells you "generatecode() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given", it's telling you that your method is set up to take no arguments, but the `self` argument is still being passed when the method is called, so in fact it is receiving one argument.

Adding `self` to your method definition should resolve the problem.

```
def generatecode(self):
    pass  # Do stuff here
```

Alternatively, you can make the method static, in which case Python will *not* pass `self` as the first argument:

```
@staticmethod
def generatecode():
    pass  # Do stuff here
```

Comment: thank you so much. this worked, now when i hit generate code it says t.insert is not defined? i posted the new code.

Comment: Right. There is no variable `t` defined anywhere (also, `read` is misspelled on that line, and it looks like you have a dot instead of a comma so those will also cause a problems).

Comment: im just trying to output a single line from the text file into a textbox using the generatecode button, but im new to python and trying to look it up but everything i have tried isnt working.

Comment: You'll need to reference that text box in your method. I'm not seeing where any text box is defined in the code you're showing here.

Comment: At any rate, it is probably better to open a new question as this one is resolved. And change your original question back to show the original code causing the error. Otherwise it's confusing to people reading this question (as the code you have there now would *not* produce the error.

Comment: after struggling for hours, I found you :}

Comment: I tried 100 other ways too.. Now I could finish my code in peace all thanks to you and stackoverflow

Answer (score 6):

I got the same error:

> TypeError: test() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

When defining an instance method without `self` and I called it as shown below:

```py
class Person:
          # ↓↓ Without "self"     
    def test(): 
        print("Test")

obj = Person()
obj.test() # Here
```

So, I put `self` to the instance method and called it:

```py
class Person:
            # ↓↓ Put "self"     
    def test(self): 
        print("Test")

obj = Person()
obj.test() # Here
```

Then, the error was solved:

```
Test
```

In addition, even if defining an instance method with `self`, we cannot call it directly by class name as shown below:

```py
class Person:
            # Here     
    def test(self): 
        print("Test")

Person.test() # Cannot call it directly by class name
```

Then, the error below occurs:

> TypeError: test() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

But, if defining an instance method without `self`, we can call it directly by class name as shown below:

```py
class Person:
          # ↓↓ Without "self"     
    def test(): 
        print("Test")

Person.test() # Can call it directly by class name
```

Then, we can get the result below without any errors:

```
Test
```

In detail, I explain about **instance method** in [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230482/what-is-an-instance-method-in-python/74482579#74482579) for [**What is an "instance method" in Python?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230482/what-is-an-instance-method-in-python) and also explain about [**@staticmethod**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) and [**@classmethod**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) in [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/classmethod-vs-staticmethod-in-python/74470227#74470227) for [**@classmethod vs @staticmethod in Python**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/classmethod-vs-staticmethod-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

The most upvoted answer does solve this issue,

And just in case anyone is doing this inside of a jupyternotebook. You must restart the kernel of the jupyternotebook in order for changes to update in the notebook