# Unable to call static method inside another static method

Tags: python, methods, static-methods

I have a class which has static methods and I want to have another static method within this class to call the method but it returns `NameError: name ''method_name' is not defined`

Example of what I'm trying to do.

```py
class abc():
    @staticmethod
    def method1():
        print('print from method1')

    @staticmethod
    def method2():
        method1()
        print('print from method2')

abc.method1()
abc.method2()
```

Output:

```
print from method1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    abc.method2()
  File "test.py", line 8, in method2
    method1()
NameError: name 'method1' is not defined
```

What is the best way to work around this?

I'd like to keep the code in this format where there is a class which contains these static methods and have them able to call each other.

Comment: What you need is a `classmethod`, not a `staticmethod`. Alternatively you can hardcode the class name and call it using `abc.method1()` from `method2`.

Comment: Even if they're static, they will be namespaced behind the class, so you need the class obj.  If it's all staticmethods you should consider using a module.

Comment: Ahh thank you. I see why it's not working now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because `method1` is a property of `abc` class, not something defined in a global scope.

You have to access it by directly referring to the class:

```py
    @staticmethod
    def method2():
        abc.method1()
        print('print from method2')
```

Or using a classmethod instead of staticmethod, which will give methods access to its class object. I recommend using this way.

```
    @classmethod
    def method2(cls): # cls refers to abc class object
        cls.method1()
        print('print from method2')
```

Answer (score 1):

[**@staticmethod**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) cannot call other static methods while [**@classmethod**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) can call them. In short, **@classmethod** is more powerful than **@staticmethod**.

I explain more about **@staticmethod** and **@classmethod** in [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/classmethod-vs-staticmethod-in-python/74470227#74470227) for [**@classmethod vs @staticmethod in Python**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/classmethod-vs-staticmethod-in-python) and also explain about **instance method** in [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230482/what-is-an-instance-method-in-python/74482579#74482579) for [**What is an "instance method" in Python?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230482/what-is-an-instance-method-in-python):